# Profile C code with dtrace

Tags: c, linux, profiling, dtrace

I was looking through stackoverflow for the best profiling technique.

I have a bunch of processes running 24/7, written in C and using Oracle 10g. I have discovered several tools I want to try: oprofile, strace, systemtap and dtrace.

I want to start with dtrace and thus I was looking for some simple dtrace script that will connect to running process' and print out all function calls, time spent in each ... maybe callgraph.
 Please, suggest some good script to start with, any links, tutorials, manuals.

Comment: Have you googled and found anything? Do you have a specific question about those tutorials? Your question right now seems to ask us to google tutorials/whatnot for you.

Comment: Yes I have. And there are a lot of scripts. And I'm just trying to find good one to start. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. No DTrace on Linux (last I heard).

If you crave for DTrace and are willing to give a real operating system a try (uh-oh, flamebait :-), try [FreeBSD](http://wiki.freebsd.org/DTrace) which comes with a functional and integrated DTrace.

Comment: Not to mention `kqueue`, which I happen to prefer over `epoll`!

Comment: I've got one from here - [link](http://www.crisp.demon.co.uk). If it's not real dtrace I should try something else :/

Comment: Interesting. Can you get it working? It's certainly not integrated with Linux, since the licenses are incompatible.

Comment: Yes I've got similar output for the first example from [DTrace for Cocoa Developers](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2008/05/dtrace-for-cocoa-developers.html). But the same command line applied to my processes somehow blocking access to oracle db ... so I'm trying to find out how to use it in right way.